# django template does not change after update or insert data MySQL

Tags: mysql, django

My website running with django, uwsgi & nginx. whenever I insert or update data to mysql, the new content that rendered to page supposed to be changed but it wasn't until I refresh the pages many times or restart the uwsgi, I'm new using django, I don't know if it has something to do with caches.

the question is how can I manage the cache at django to maintain the database access in order to direct any changes in the page without restarting the uwsgi. Thank you.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. Django does not cache templates by default. Please post the template code that is problematic and the related view code.

Answer (score -2):

Try to apply migration.Applying migration will update your database and the try to run server or visit your website it will show you change.
If you're at Django1.8+
*use this command for migration:*
**python manage.py makemigrations**

*and after that use migrate command:*
**python manage.py migrate**

*and then run your server or relode the webpage.*

hope it solve your issue

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question that was asked.